# Get Options Value Using Tag Name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML

```
<select id="tempSelect" >
    <option value="F">Fahrenheit</option>
    <option value="C">Celsius</option>
</select>
```

I want to get the selected Option Value **using Tag Name  Not ID** .
I tried this using document.getElementById()  it works fine but I want to do it by tag name.
I searched a lot but could not found the solution so far.

Here is my Java script Code

```
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
var tempUnit = parent.options[parent.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[document.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)(which is a kind of an array), so it does have the `options` properties. You can access the items in the list using indexing.

```js
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
var tempUnit = parent.options[parent.selectedIndex].value;

document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = tempUnit
```

```html
<select id="tempSelect" >
    <option value="F">Fahrenheit</option>
    <option value="C" selected>Celsius</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```